# HTML tag Textarea in Angular 6 creating white block at top of screen

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-bootstrap

I've created a form in a component.html in project using Angular 6. I've created a `textarea` element inside the form and gave it a bootstrap class `form-control`. When I clicked on the textArea the upper part of my HTML page got refreshed and then returned to normal. This behavior occurs only on the first click. 
I removed the bootstrap class `form-control` and it worked fine. I replicated & tried the code in my friend's system and the behavior was the same. That made me think the anomaly occurred because of `form-control` class. The anomaly occurs only in the current version of Angular ie. 6. In earlier versions of it, it didn't happen.

Images and code are attached for the reference.

This is the form before clicking or going to the `textarea`.

[image]

Form after clicking or going to the `textarea`.

[image]

Here's my code for the generated form.

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Email:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Password:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10"> 
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group"> 
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="comment">Comment</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" cols="2" rows="5" id="comment"></textarea>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the issue in a Stackblitz, and post the link here to demonstrate?

Comment: Yes, I tried it after you commented and it produced the same behavior. Link- https://xvljjerybxj.angular.stackblitz.io/dashboard

Comment: Without a [mcve] I don't know if anyone can help

Comment: @KartikChauhan - The stackblitz that you refer to does not load properly.

Comment: This is the only HTML file I had in my project. My installed bootstrap version is 4.1.3. You can check the project on stackblitz. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jvzg5v

Comment: Seems to behave normally when I try. Which browser are you using?

Comment: @user184994 could you please try it in a new browser window with the app url. I'm using Chrome though.

Comment: Same result for me as for @user184994. What kind of computer do you use?

Comment: @ConnorsFan A computer in which chrome can smoothly run. Check this link https://angular-jvzg5v.stackblitz.io